# check for username against password in base controller mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to know how can I force a user to log in the the application again if the page is being opened in new tab or new browser.

Edit:-

My apologies I misunderstood the requirement.

I am authenticating the user in my log-in page but not anywhere else. So what is happening because of that, even if i log out of application and type url say bla.com/apple I can access my application.

I figured to prevent this from happening, I have to write a base controller that checks for the right user. Am I moving in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? Forms? Windows? Claims?

Comment: As i am not familiar with Authentication. I am just checking username against password. I have a WCF that accepts userName and password and return a bool. If true -> welcome to the application if false -> try again. Should i user any of the mentioned authentication. Which one do you suggest I have to make  my application very secure as it contains very sensitive information.

Comment: How is this a security issue? If the user is authenticated, why shouldn't they be able to open a new tab? And when you say 'new browser', same browser type or cross-browser? If cross, it'll be handled automatically as the other one won't have the authentication token or session.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the edit -

Authentication can be handled per controller or on individual actions. Simple place the [Authorize] attribute appropriately. This assumes however that somewhere an authentication token is being set. [Authorize] checks against the HttpContext's current User (an IPrincipal).

You mentioned above that you're just validating against a local username and password, in one place, so I'm guessing that no token (session, cookie) are being set?

You have a few options here to get that token stored and persisted across requests:

- ASP.Net integrated membership provider ([Intro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.98%29.aspx))
- A custom [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) ([Example](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider))
- Full-on custom flow. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633137/asp-net-mvc-forms-authentication-against-external-web-service/5633161#5633161))

Each has ups and downs and depends on how exactly you want to handle on-boarding your users. It's hard to answer more specifically because it can be a very large topic (and a very broad question).

Here's the [official pages for MVC security](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security).